# Sphinx make html fails: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have an error with Sphinx Autodoc.

I am not sure why it can't find those modules.

**My project structure is:**

```
    Project
    |
    |--Main Folder
    |    |--docs
    |        _build
    |        _static
    |        _templates
    |        conf.py
    |        index.rst
    |        make.bat
    |        Makefile
    |        modules.rst
    |        program.rst
    |    |--program
    |          __init__.py
    |          Camera.py
    |          Database.py
    |          Dataset.py
    |          Detection.py
    |          ...
```

**conf.py**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))


extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon'
]

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = []
```

**modules.rst**

```
program
=======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   program
```

**Detection.py**  Just the first lines from the import

```
from Camera import Camera
```

**The Error**

The weird thing is that Sphinx can create the documentation for the Camera file with easy, but it fails with the following error:

`WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'Detection' from module 'program'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'Camera'`

So this is because in `Detection.py` I import my `Camera.py`.

Does someone see my error?
Because in the program, the imports work fine and I can access all the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
from program.Camera import Camera
```

or

```
from .Camera import Camera
```